# How to add Extra Parameter(messageID) to JSQMessagesViewController in Swift 3?

Tags: swift3, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am using `JSQMessagesViewController`,I know it's depreciated but still i want to use, I want to add extra parameter with `messageID` to `Objective-C` file `JSQMessage.h` & `JSQMessage.m` because it has its default paramter's

```
- (instancetype)initWithSenderId:(NSString *)senderId
senderDisplayName:(NSString *)senderDisplayName
date:(NSDate *)date
text:(NSString *)text;
```

So i want to add `messageID` so that i can use it at the time of receiving and sending messages with default its working fine